# AWS API Gateway Custom Authorizer Role Validation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Is there any way of specifying allowed scopes on an API Gateway method such that the allowed scopes are passed to a custom authorizer and validated against the scopes claim in an access token.

E.g. a get users endpoint might be available to all users but a create user endpoint only available to an users with the create:user scope. As well as ensuring the access token is valid the custom authorizer would check the scope claim in the token and compare it to the allowed scopes for the method.

Would prefer not to have to write a different authorizer function for each combination of required scopes.

I notice something like this is possible with Cognito, but my identity provider / token issuer is Auth0 so using Lambda function to validate the access token

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use single Lambda Authorizer to protect both endpoints based on the token scope. You will want to use Request based [Enhanced Lambda Authorizer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-enhanced-request-authorizers-in-amazon-api-gateway/)

You pass the access token in the `Authorization` header and verify the access token signature and expiration before processing the request.

An example of `Event` object received by the authorizer:

```
{
    "methodArn": "arn:aws:execute-api:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXX:xxxxxx/dev/GET/hello",
    "resource": "/hello",
    "requestContext": {
        "resourceId": "xxxx",
        "apiId": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "resourcePath": "/hello",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "requestId": "9e04ff18-98a6-11e7-9311-ef19ba18fc8a",
        "path": "/dev/hello",
        "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "identity": {
            "apiKey": "",
            "sourceIp": "58.240.196.186"
        },
        "stage": "dev"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": {},
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "pathParameters": {},
    "headers": {
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
        "x-amzn-ssl-client-hello": "AQACJAMDAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA…",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "54.240.196.186, 54.182.214.90",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "User-Agent": "PostmanRuntime/6.2.5",
        "Authorization": "hello"
    },
    "stageVariables": {},
    "path": "/hello",
    "type": "REQUEST"
}
```

You can identify the request by combination of `event.requestContext.resourcePath` and `event.requestContext.httpMethod`. Based on the request type and the scope defined in the token you can return Allowed or Denied policy. If, for example, request is for create user endpoint but access token don't include `create:user` scope then you will return policy to deny the request.

Comment: ok so i would need to bake in passing of the resource path into the function rather than being able to add some arbitrary extra param to my resources e.g. AllowedScopes, the latter would be preferable as each time i add a resource i wouldnt need to update the authorizer to parse the new resource path, but I can see how at least this could work if that is not possible

Comment: Yes you will need to update Lambda Authorizer each time you've a new resource with custom requirements.